# Returning only the first common node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a query which returns only the first common node between two nodes in a scenario where there may be multiple.

Using this graph for reference - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-friend-finding.html.

For example, I'm Joe, and I would like to find the list of friend-of-friends I don't know, with only one person that I should ask for an introduction. An example return set is this, even though Bill is also a connection to Ian:

```
Bill    Derrick
Sara    Ian
Sara    Jill
```

I've tried using `DISTINCT`, but that doesn't group properly:

```
MATCH (joe { name: 'Joe' })-[:knows]-(friend)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)
WHERE NOT (joe)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)
WITH DISTINCT friend_of_friend, friend
RETURN friend.name, friend_of_friend.name
```

I'm starting to believe I need a second query with the `friend` node passed to it. Hopefully not though, because that sounds painfully inefficient. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do an aggregation on level of friend using the collect function:

```
MATCH (joe { name: 'Joe' })-[:knows]-(friend)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)
WHERE NOT (joe)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)    
RETURN friend.name, collect(friend_of_friend.name)
```

### update

```
MATCH path=(joe { name: 'Joe' })-[:knows]-(friend)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)
WHERE NOT (joe)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend)
RETURN collect(friend)[0] AS friend, friend_of_friend
```

This gives you 3 rows:

- Bill, Derrick
- Bill, Ian or Sara, Ian
- Sara, Jill

Here it's not deterministic if Bill-Ian or Sara-Ian is in the result.

Comment: Is this a shorthand way of saying "You can't get the result set you're looking for"? That gives me one row for each friend, and a collection of friend_of_friends. Is there a follow-up trick to convert this to what I'm looking for?

Comment: OK, I got it. The last step was to chop the collection to include only the first element. Rearranged a bit to provide results in the manner I'm looking for:  `MATCH (joe { name: 'Joe' })-[:knows]-(friend)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend) WHERE NOT (joe)-[:knows]-(friend_of_friend) WITH friend_of_friend, collect(friend) AS collectFriends RETURN collectFriends[0], friend_of_friend`

Comment: I guess I've misread your question, see updated answer above:

Comment: There we go, we got there. Thanks!  My business case calls for using only one of the connecting nodes in a subsequent MATCH. The UI is such that viewing the node directly shows all the friends-of-friends, though.